# Radio Group as item in listview custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, radio-button, radio-group

I have made a custom adapter having different view types. I am showing two views are textview and radiogroup having variable buttons. I have written this code:

This is my model class for different views

```
public class OrthoScaleModel {

    public static int SECONDARY_TEXTVIEW = 0;
    public static int RADIOGROUP_TEXTVIEW = 1;

    public int type;
    public String[] radioButtonArray;
    public String headingTitle;
    public int numberOfRadioButtons;

    public OrthoScaleModel(int type, String[] radioButtonArray, String headingTitle
    , int numberOfRadioButtons) {
        this.type = type;
        this.radioButtonArray = radioButtonArray;
        this.headingTitle = headingTitle;
        this.numberOfRadioButtons = numberOfRadioButtons;
    }
}
```

And this is my custom adapter getView() method code

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    OrthoScaleModel model = list.get(position);

    for (String data : model.radioButtonArray){
        Log.v("Data", data);
    }

    RadioButton[] buttons = new RadioButton[model.numberOfRadioButtons];

    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        if (type == 0){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondary_heading, parent, false);
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondaryHeadingTextView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else if (type == 1){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.textview_radiogroup, parent, false);
            holder.radioGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio_group1);

            for (int i = 0; i < model.numberOfRadioButtons; i++){
                buttons[i] = new RadioButton(context);
                holder.radioGroup.addView(buttons[i]);
                buttons[i].setText(list.get(position).radioButtonArray[i]);
                buttons[i].setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
                buttons[i].setPadding(0, 5, 5, 0);
                buttons[i].setTextSize(18);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (type == 0){
        holder.textView.setText(model.headingTitle);
    }

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    private TextView textView;
    private RadioGroup radioGroup;
}
```

And I used it to get my listview as

```
  ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        String[] orthoScalesData = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ortho_scales_data);
ArrayList<OrthoScaleModel> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1.add(new OrthoScaleModel(OrthoScaleModel.SECONDARY_TEXTVIEW, new String[]{}, orthoScalesData[1], 0));

            list1.add(new OrthoScaleModel(OrthoScaleModel.SECONDARY_TEXTVIEW, new String[]{}, orthoScalesData[2], 0));
            list1.add(new OrthoScaleModel(OrthoScaleModel.RADIOGROUP_TEXTVIEW, new String[]{orthoScalesData[3],
                    orthoScalesData[4], orthoScalesData[5], orthoScalesData[6], orthoScalesData[7], orthoScalesData[8]},
                    " ", 6));

            list1.add(new OrthoScaleModel(OrthoScaleModel.SECONDARY_TEXTVIEW, new String[]{}, orthoScalesData[9], 0));
            list1.add(new OrthoScaleModel(OrthoScaleModel.RADIOGROUP_TEXTVIEW, new String[]{orthoScalesData[10],
                    orthoScalesData[11], orthoScalesData[12], orthoScalesData[13], orthoScalesData[14], orthoScalesData[15]},
                    " ", 6));

            CustomOrthoScaleAdapter adapter = new CustomOrthoScaleAdapter(this, list1);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But In my listview I am getting same radio button text for both radio group position.Please somebody help.

Answer (score 0):

Add `holder.radioGroup.addView(buttons[i])` at the end of for loop before setting tag

```
 for (int i = 0; i < model.numberOfRadioButtons; i++){
                buttons[i] = new RadioButton(context);  
                buttons[i].setText(list.get(position).radioButtonArray[i]);
                buttons[i].setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
                buttons[i].setPadding(0, 5, 5, 0);
                buttons[i].setTextSize(18);
                holder.radioGroup.addView(buttons[i]);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its common mistake with getView method.  First you should get the convertView and finally set the content for them.  Try this..

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    OrthoScaleModel model = list.get(position);

    for (String data : model.radioButtonArray){
        Log.v("Data", data);
    }

    RadioButton[] buttons = new RadioButton[model.numberOfRadioButtons];

    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        if (type == 0){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondary_heading, parent, false);
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondaryHeadingTextView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else if (type == 1){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.textview_radiogroup, parent, false);
            holder.radioGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio_group1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
///Added///////////////////////////////
    if(holder.radioGroup!=null){
            for (int i = 0; i < model.numberOfRadioButtons; i++){
                buttons[i] = new RadioButton(context);
                holder.radioGroup.addView(buttons[i]);
                buttons[i].setText(list.get(position).radioButtonArray[i]);
                buttons[i].setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
                buttons[i].setPadding(0, 5, 5, 0);
                buttons[i].setTextSize(18);
                //convertView.setTag(holder);///not needed///
            }
    }
///Added///////////////////////////////
    if (type == 0){
        holder.textView.setText(model.headingTitle);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```